# Filter a list based on .attr() and .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So I've created a list with a basic text filter using .each(), and it's working, however I'm looking to filter based on a match in either a custom attribute (data-tag) OR the contents of the link *text*.  See below..

```
$(document).on("input", "#find-link", function() {
    // Get the value of the textbox
    var linkSearchValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // Cycle through the list of links
    $(".link").each(function(i) {
        // If the searchbox is NOT empty
        if (linkSearchValue != "") {
           // Get the tags and text to compare against
           var linkTags = $(this).attr("data-tag");
           var linkText = $(this).text();
           if ( (!linkTags.toLowerCase().includes(linkSearchValue)) || (!linkText.toLowerCase().includes(linkSearchValue)) ) { // Check if the search string DOESN'T match...
               // If there isn't a match for a link, hide it.
               $(this).addClass("hidden-link");
           } else {
               // If there IS a match for a link, show it.
               $(this).removeClass("hidden-link");
           }
        } else {
           $(this).removeClass("hidden-link");
        }
    });
});
```

In the section

```
if ( (!linkTags.toLowerCase().includes(linkSearchValue)) || (!linkText.toLowerCase().includes(linkSearchValue)) ) { // Check if the search string DOESN'T match...
```

It works fine if I check JUST linkTags, or JUST linkText, but not both... if I check both, it ONLY checks linkTags.

Why isn't it checking both?

Comment: Hide all elements first. Then loop through the elements, and remove the `hidden-link` class if either of the conditions matches.

Comment: Boolean comparison operators short-circuit, so if `(!linkTags.toLowerCase().includes(linkSearchValue))` evaluates to true, it doesn't bother evaluating the second condition because `true || false` is true, and `true || true` is true, so there's no need.

Comment: You should use `&&`, not `||`. [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: @Barmar I think I tried that already but no changes were made.  For hiding elements and THEN looping through them.  That said, using `&&` works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't recall having that happen to me before... and what if the first condition is false?  If the second condition was true, shouldn't `false || true = true`?  Or as @Barmar mentioned in the second comment, does it have something to do with me using the NOT operator?

Comment: If the first condition is false, it will evaluate the second condition, yes, and should fall through if that second condition is true. But you have to make sure you're evaluating the conditions correctly. What I usually do is something like `console.log(!!firstCondition); console.log(!!secondCondition);` before the `if` so I know exactly what JavaScript thinks the conditions evaluate to in terms of Booleans (not truthy/falsy). Sometimes I just make Boolean variables with the conditions and use those in the `if`, just so no one after me gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Using `&&` instead of `||` resolved the issue, as explained by @Barmar in the comments.  Taking from the link they posted for [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)...

1. not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
2. not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)

Because I am looking for EITHER expression to not contain the words searched, I would opt to use the first format (since it's NOT A or B, I'd search for NOT A, *and* NOT B).

It's still a little confusing, but since no answer was given (just comments), and the comment solved the issue, I'll place it as an answer.